# ESP8266 with Arduino Uno and HTTP POST

Tags: esp8266

Im currently new on this and sucessfully made a sound-activated alarm with Arduino Uno and a microphone sensor. (If sound is detected, then it will alarm). Now, I am adding a ESP 8266 module into it so it can perform a HTTP GET or POST to IFTT Maker link.

My problem with it is how can I program the esp with arduino uno? Do I do something like this

> https://github.com/bportaluri/WiFiEsp/blob/master/examples/WebClient/WebClient.ino

(and add the threshold for the microphone sensor, buzzers and LEDs)??

Thanks for helping

Comment: That would work if your ESP8266 had the AT+ firmware flashed onto it by default. What exact module do you have? If you have a NodeMCU board you might as well work on the ESP8266 directly for everything

Comment: Im using the small one with 8 pins (esp-01). Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the library

- https://github.com/bportaluri/WiFiEsp

Is suited for your task because it implements talking to a ESP8266 over a software serial. On this serial connection, AT+ commands will be sent. This also means that you must have the AT firmware flashed onto your ESP-01.

If that is not the case you can download the binary image [here](http://www.electrodragon.com/w/ESP8266_AT-Command_firmware) and flash it with a serial adapter, as instructed with the tools on that page. You can check whether your ESP8266 has the firmware flashed by attach a UART adpater to the TX output. It should print a "ready" on bootup.

For your wire-up, you will just have to add VCC (+3.3V), GND, TX and RX connections to the ESP-01 board, preferable with a big capacitor between VCC and GND, as the ESP8266 draws a lot of power when sending data over WiFi.

Comment: Is it ok if i use something like this to connect so can use 5V instead? [link](https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1Z6oshRfH8KJjy1Xbq6zLdXXaC/OPEN-SMART-ESP8266-Serial-Wi-Fi-Wireless-ESP-01-Adapter-Module-3-3V-5V-Compatible-for.jpg_640x640.jpg)

Comment: @HenrikhA. The ESP8266 is a 3.3V device, if you supply it with 5V it dies. It should also not receive a 5V signal. You will need a level shifter from the Arduino TX line to the ESP's RX line with a voltage divider. See http://www.martyncurrey.com/arduino-to-esp8266-serial-commincation/

Comment: @HenrikhA. Ah, I didn't see the link at the end. Yes, the adapter has a voltage regulator and bi-directional level shifters already on there. This module should be fine and you could give +5V (or V_USB) as VCC on there.

Comment: I think I know what to do now. Thanks @Maximilian